# How do analyse a Panel Data with HDI as the independent variable and Case fatality Rate and Number of cases as the dependent variables?

Tags: panel-data, dataset

I have Covid-19 Case fatality rate and Number of cases for 37 states as dependent variables and HD Index of the 37 States as the independent variable. That is a single predictor and multiple responses. I want to use Fixed Effect Model (panel data) to show the effect of Human Development Index (HDIs) on   Case fatality rate and number of   cases of of Covid-19 with time period of 2 years(2020 and 2021).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Specifically, there's not *much* you can do with this, the data are very crude. Why haven't you considered a linear regression for instance?